# How to fix a Permalink that is not working in WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, permalinks

I have a WordPress "tube" theme. When I click on a thumbnail, it opens a new page which is my homepage! (It is supposed to take me to the post page) but I can type in the post page address to go there manually. How can I fix this in code? Here's a piece of code in image.php. i know some PHP but not very fluent so i can't quite connect the dots.

```
<header class="entry-header">
                <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>

                <div class="entry-meta">

                    <span class="entry-date"><time class="entry-date" datetime="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( get_the_date() ); ?></time></span>

                    <span class="full-size-link"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_get_attachment_url() ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $metadata['width'] ); ?> &times; <?php echo esc_html( $metadata['height'] ); ?></a></span>

                    <span class="parent-post-link"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $post->post_parent ) ); ?>" rel="gallery"><?php echo get_the_title( $post->post_parent ); ?></a></span>
                    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyfourteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

Comment: Did you try re-saving permalinks? That you fix any issue with permalink structure (if there are any)

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to the actual post link.

maybe try to replace

```
post->post_parent
```

with:

```
post->ID
```

Comment: I tried "post->post->ID" , "$post->post->ID" , "post->post_ID" , "$post->post_ID" none of them worked :(

Comment: Ah my apologies, that was a typo. Could you try  $post->ID?

Comment: No, it still doesn't work, is it possible that I'm editing the wrong file?

Comment: Two things i have to mention about my theme:   1. when i add a category to my posts it shows as "girls"! So its like "girls: category1, category2, etc." And also when i add tags it's like "niches: tag1, tag2, etc." So I'm thinking maybe the naming for permalinks is off somewhere in the code? 2.  My permalinks in the post settings of wordpress is in this format : "homepageURL/date/post-title" just thought maybe this helps i don't know!

Comment: I don't wanna push it, but if you want i can give you a sample url of a site with this theme + the original link to the theme.

Comment: Oeps sorry for the late reply. Yeah sure!